# Is "It was she did" grammatically correct?

Tags: subjects, reduced-relative-clauses

Someone asks me who did it if I answer

> "It was she did"

Is it correct? Or is it preferable to say

> "It was she who did it"

or other answer

Comment: No. That's incorrect.

Comment: "It was she [**who** did [the act]]" is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

I actually did not know what you intended at first by *It was she did*: it simply isn't grammatical in English.

Once I saw your actual question, I realised that you are trying to omit a relative pronoun (*who* or *that*).

Relative pronouns can often be omitted;

> It was the book that she was reading -> It was the book she was reading

but not in standard Englishes when they function as the subject of thre relative clause:

> *It was she who did it* but not *It was she did it*.

(Some dialects do allow this, but not any standard English).

There is a further complication: *do* is not normally used without an object, unless it is acting as a sort of "pro-verb": referring back to an action already discussed.

So

> *Who ate the cake?*  *She did!* or *It was her who did*.

But without that prior question those sentences are very odd. *It was her who did the shopping* is fine.

So your *It was she who did it* is fine; but *It was she who did* would be odd without that context.

One final point: you may notice that I have use *her* in my examples, rather than *she*. The old-fashioned grammars all tell you that you should use *she* (*he*, *I*, *we*) after "to be" (*is*,*was*, etc). Many people still do so, especially in formal contexts. But most people, at least in everyday speech, use *her* (*me*, *him*, *us*).

Answer (score -1):

"It was she did" is incorrect.

"It was her" would be correct.

Comment: Good answers contain explanations not only corrections. Please explain, in your post, why the object pronoun i(her) s preferred over the subject (she).